# CSS :before/:after Selectors in IE 6,7

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I know that :before/:after selectors are not available in IE 6,7
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Is there a js hack to enable support for these selectors in IE?

Comment: Contrary to what that table says, IE8 *does* support `:before` and `:after`. Perhaps it's just not entirely correct support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course jQueries [before](http://api.jquery.com/before) and [after](http://api.jquery.com/after)

what else ;)

Comment: this is the best way! Why I didn't think of this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There's a Javascript solution called IE7, it fixes common IE bugs: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: Some of the older *modular* files for IE7.js available at http://reisio.com/temp/ie7-js/, including among others _ie7-css2-selectors.js_.

Comment: Within that project, you'll want to use either IE8.js or IE9.js for `:before` and `:after` support, as Microsoft added them to IE8, not IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well it works; but a quick search found a promising result:

http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/

> CSS2's :before and :after
>   pseudo-selectors are really handy ...
>   but they don't work in Internet
>   Explorer. Nope, not even IE7. I bet
>   you're thinking: "But what if we used
>   as many proprietary Microsoft features
>   as possible all at the same time,
>   that'll show 'em!" And you know what?
>   You're absolutely right. You've just
>   gotta love that this —  * { behavior:
>   expression(...); } — can (more or
>   less) enable :before and :after for
>   IE5.5+
>
> With jquery.pseudo.js in the 
>   of your document, you can then do:

```
p:before, p {
    before: 'foo';
    content: 'foo'; }

p:before, p .before {
    color: blue; }
```

Comment: did you notice the 'Updated: February 6th, 2006' message on that page?

Comment: I did, but IE7 has been around an awful long time, so I disregarded the age of the page.

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery you can bosh in the supposrt wherever you like, bit like this nugget

```
 /* fix top nav ui in ie6*/
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6 ) {
    $('#topNav ul li a:not(:last)').after("/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this when trying to to create this https://gist.github.com/1133433 with support for IE 6 and 7. I had tried to use the CSS3 flexible box model, but hit a bug in web-kit when using the CSS3 Flexible Box w/ box-sizing: border-box, padding and fixed widths. It breaks the default box-align: stretch (equal heights). It was either this or resolve to use a table.

The CSS3 Flexible Box seems to hard to control. If you want to set fixed widths, and reap the benefits of box-align: stretch as well as set the padding, you're SOL.