# Alternative solution to css pseudo element :before for IE6/7

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, pseudo-element

I've created a slide carousel and it uses pseudo element :before to identify the current item you are on, however pseudo element isn't supported in IE6/7.

Wondering if anyone can think of an alternate solution to have pseudo element working for IE6/7.

Here's what my page looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcwta/

JavaScript solutions are acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woudl add an extra element to the dom as follows.

Javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
            slideCount += '<li id="slide'+ i+'"><span class="highlight"></span><span>'+(i+1)+'</span></li>' ;
        }
```

Css

```
#carousel #slideCount li .highlight {
    display:none;
}

#carousel #slideCount li.current .highlight,
#carousel #slideCount .test {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 201px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) in the past, works quite well and adds the :before/:after 'element's along with other niceties.

That's the only solution I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery, it supports the [`:before` selector](http://api.jquery.com/before/) also for IE 6. See also [CSS :before/:after Selectors in IE 6,7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844687/css-before-after-selectors-in-ie-6-7)

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't seem to behave like the :before pseudo element. because my pseudo class is position absolute, when I use jQuery to do it for IE6, it just positions the element absolute to the parent instead of the element itself. Have a look at my fiddle if you have time.