# How to use :before :after in IE6,7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors, internet-explorer-6

The css code is this:

```
div.quote:before {
  content: 'before';
}
div.quote:after { 
  content: 'after'; 
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with IE 6 and 7. How can I solve it? Maybe with expression?

Comment: IE6 was officially marked as deprecated by Microsoft in January 2012.

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844687/css-before-after-selectors-in-ie-6-7

Comment: May I know why you removed the duplicate link?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you may have a look at 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

neither :before and :after, nor content, are supported css selectors and properties for css in  IE7 and before..

you might achieve a similar effect with [javascript](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/) though